# Prevent a method that is called in the parent constructor from being called in the child constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Suppose I have a parent class and a child class that inherits from the parent.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self)
    stubborn()

class Child():
      def __init__(self):
      super().__init__(self)
```

***I do not want the stubborn method to be called anytime I call the parent constructor 
in the child class. How do I approach this?***

Comment: A total re-design. You'd have to change `Parent.__init__`.

Comment: Add an optional parameter to `Parent` ctor: `def __init__(self, call_stubborn=True):`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `classmethod` of `Parent` that checks whether or not you are in `Parent`, then use that to determine whether to call `stubborn`

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        if self.is_parent():
            self.stubborn()
    @classmethod
    def is_parent(cls):
        return cls is Parent
    def stubborn(self):
        print("stubborn called")

class Child(Parent): pass

p = Parent() # stubborn called
c = Child() # no output
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to do anything about it in `parent.__init__()` without actually changing that function or `stubborn()`.

But, as the child, you could stop the `stubborn()` method from doing anything important by temporarily making it a stub:

```
class Child():
    def __init__(self):
        old_stubborn = self.stubborn
        self.stubborn = lambda:None  # stub function that does nothing
        super().__init__(self)
        # put stubborn() back to normal
        self.stubborn = old_stubborn
```

Comment: Ooohhh, nasty!  I guess this example helps put the "dynamic" in "dynamic language"!